# jQuery hover that changes various backgrounds with infinite loop until mouse is out

Tags: jquery, timeout

I've a `<div>` with a background-image that will change the background 4 times with a delay of 300ms. I've tried with setTimeout which seems to work correct, but clearTimeout(t); when the mouse moves out fails because the backgrounds continue changing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image").hover(function(){
        var obj = $('.image');
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 -90");
        var t=setTimeout(function(){obj.css("background-position", "0 -180")}, 300);
        var t=setTimeout(function(){obj.css("background-position", "0 -270")}, 600);
        var t=setTimeout(function(){obj.css("background-position", "0 -360")}, 900);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 0");
        clearTimeout(t);
    });
});
```

I would like too to insert to the hover function a way to have a infinite loop until the mouse is released.

Sorry for my school English.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move the t var dec outside of the function.  then it will be in the closure.

eg something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t1,t2,t3;

    $(".image").hover(function(){
        var obj = $('.image');
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 -90");
        var t1=setTimeout(function(){obj.css("background-position", "0 -180")}, 300);
        var t2=setTimeout(function(){obj.css("background-position", "0 -270")}, 600);
        var t3=setTimeout(function(){obj.css("background-position", "0 -360")}, 900);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background-position", "0 0");
        clearTimeout(t1);
        clearTimeout(t2);
        clearTimeout(t3);
    });
});
```

There are other issues with this code but I'm just answering the question.

Comment: thank for your reply! But I can't get it working... don't understand why but I think that it's not the way to go from the start (my fail)... how can I orientate it to a good way? thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you use the code above?  In what ways is it not working?  If you put the problem code in jsfiddle, then helping you would be simpler.

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle, but i tihnk that this is right: http://jsfiddle.net/NhpVW/3/

Answer (score 1):

Because with this the variable `t` is overwritten twice by the two previous `setTimeout`s, so only the code for the last `setTimeout` is preserved, so when you call `clearTimeout` you're only clearing the last `setTimeout`.

What you can do is to use three different variables to store this, change to `setInterval` instead, or use a loop to set the timeouts.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Thanks! And how can I make a infinite loop until is released?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [jquery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)? Would probably simplify things a lot -- they'll deal with all the timers and stuff for you. It's baked into the library you're already using so why not take advantage of it?

```
$('.image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 -360px)"}, 
        {duration:1800})
    })
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
        {duration:100})
    });
```

By default it's going to use a liniar animation, but you could set up different [easing](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing) if you wanted something different.

Comment: I can't use animation, i think, becasue the background image is 5 frames from a video. :(